# .appendChild is not a function

Tags: javascript, dom, parent-child

I'm trying to add some elements to the DOM, but the FireBug console keep alerting me for an error saying `TypeError: el.appendChild is not a function; el.appendChild(para);` So here is the js:

```
var para = document.createElement("tr");
var node = document.createTextNode(data.filename);
para.appendChild(node);
var el = document.getElementsByClassName("toBeSelected");              
el.appendChild(para);
```

Found some common problems but couldn't find a way to solve mine.

Comment: Why did you tag jQuery if you're not even using it?

Comment: This code I posted is a part of an AJAX request. That's why I tagged jQuery. I did it inadvertently

Comment: one useful function for you to figure out what is available. console.dir()

Comment: If I want to add a `class` to the created `tr` tag, how would this be achieved

Answer (score 4):

```
document.getElementsByClassName
                   ^
```

returns a *collection* of elements. You need to select an element from the collection before you can append a child to it.

If you know there's **exactly** one, you could use:

```
var el = document.getElementsByClassName("toBeSelected")[0];
```

As it's unclear whether you expect to add nodes to all of the elements with the given class, so I will explicitly assume that is what you expect to do.

```
elems = document.getElementsByClassName('toBeSelected');
for (i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
  elem = elems[i];
  tr = document.createElement('tr');
  tr.textContent = data.filename;
  elem.appendChild(tr);
}
```

This form is quite verbose. If you're using jQuery, then it's much simpler to write:

```
$('<tr>').text(data.filename).appendTo('.toBeSelected');
```

Comment: Yeah, tried `el[0].appendChild(para);` and worked

Comment: If I want to add a `class` to the created `tr` tag, how would this be achieved

Comment: @Alex, there are numerous resources for learning JavaScript basics online. The first and foremost is Google, but MDN and StackOverflow both are good resources for learning syntax and APIs. Please exert a bit of effort in solving your own problems before asking for help.